Is it possible to prove that the fundamental group functor evaluates the same on homotopic maps by assuming the product rule?
Essentially title, presume that I know the product rule of the fundamental group functor:

$$\pi( X \times Y, (x_o,y_o) ) \simeq \pi(X,x_o) \times \pi(Y,y_o)$$

Could I prove that homotopic maps evaluate the same?

My try
Let $(X,x_o)$ and $(Y,y_o)$ be two pointed topological spaces, and $f,g: X \to Y$ with $f,g$ homotopic. This means there is a continou function $H: X \times [0,1] \to Y$ with the property that $H(x,0)=f$ , $H(x,1)=g$ , $H(x_o,t)=y_o$.
We apply the fundamental group functor keeping base points of left side as $(x_o,t_o)$ on the following diagram:
$$ X \times [0,1] \overset{H}{\to} Y$$
We have with product rule that:
$$ F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg) \times F\bigg( (\left[ 0,1\right],t_o)\bigg) \overset{F(H)}{\to} F\bigg((Y,y_o) \bigg)$$
The fundamental group$ F\bigg( (\left[ 0,1\right],t_o)\bigg) $ is simply the trivial group, we have then:
$$ F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg) \times \{ * \}  \overset{F(H)}{\to} F\bigg((Y,y_o) \bigg)$$
I know that $F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg) \times \{ * \} \simeq  F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg)$. We could, with what I consider as abuse of notation (maybe really is) write:
$$ F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg) \overset{F(H)}{\to} F\bigg((Y,y_o )\bigg)$$
I really think the fact that homotopic maps evaluate the same under fundamental group should come out from this but I am not sure how to manipulate it more...

Note:
$F$ is the fundamental group functor
Evaluate the same mean, if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic then $F(f)=F(g)$
My question is different from this post because this one is a proof with a modified assumption, where the point is to make clear the categorical view point of the fundamental group

I think in the definition of $H$, you meant $H(x_0,t)=y_0$? Because $H(0,t)$ and $H(1,t)$ really does not make sense since $0,1$ are not elements of $X$.

It is unclear to me what "homotopic maps evaluate the same" means.

@KritikerderElche I believe they mean that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then $\pi(f)=\pi(g)$.

What is $ F\bigg((X,x_o) \bigg)$?

It's the fundamental group functor @KritikerderElche

You are correct @HackR I edited it now.

Why do you write $F$ instead of $\pi$?

@KritikerderElche Geschmacks sache

If we assume naturality of your product isomorphism and the triviality of $\pi(I)$ and $\pi(*)$ then the the proof goes through.
Let $F\colon \mathsf{Top}_* \to \mathsf{Grp}$ be a functor. Write the product functor $\times \colon \mathsf{Top}_*^2 \to \mathsf{Top}_*$.
Similarly write $\times \colon \mathsf{Grp}^2 \to \mathsf{Grp}$. Considering the parallel functors $F \circ \times$ and $\times \circ (F, F)\colon \mathsf{Top}_*^2 \to \mathsf{Grp}$, suppose we have a natural isomorphism $\eta \colon F \circ \times \Rightarrow \times \circ (F, F)$. Further suppose that $FI$ and $F*$ are the trivial group.
Let $X, Y$ be based spaces. Write $p \colon X \times I \to X$ for the projection.

Lemma: $F(p)$ is an isomorphism.

Proof: Write $X \times \{*\} \xrightarrow{\alpha} X$ for the obvious homeomorphism. Note that $p$ is the composition $X \times I \xrightarrow{\operatorname{id} \times *} X \times * \xrightarrow{\alpha} X$.
Consider the naturality square for $\eta$ applied to the morphism $(\operatorname{id},*) \colon (X, I) \to (X, *)$ in $\mathsf{Top}_*^2$.

The bottom arrow is an isomorphism because $F(\operatorname{id})$ and $F(*)$ are isomorphisms. The vertical maps are isomorphisms by assumption about $\eta$, so naturality gives that the top map $F(\operatorname{id} \times *)$ is an isomorphism. The map $F(\alpha)$ is also an isomorphism because $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, so we can conclude that $F(p)$ is an isomorphism.

Claim: If $f, g \colon X \to Y$ are homotopic then $F(f)=F(g)$.

The proof is at Homotopy invariance of functors, and only uses the fact that each $F(p)$ is an isomorphism.

I need to think more naturality
